# util.inspect behaves differently on different node versions

Tags: javascript, node.js

code:

```
var util = require('util')
var body = '{doc}'
try{
  body = JSON.parse(body)
}catch(err){
  console.log(util.inspect(err))
}
```

The same code running on different versions giving different results

node 6.x.x: (inspect is not working)

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 1
    at Object.parse (native)
```

on node 0.x.x:

```
[SyntaxError: Unexpected token i]
```

PS: I have used depth null, still am getting same results on nodev6

Answer (score 0):

It's not that it's not working, it's just that the `util.inspect()` implementation changed between the major node versions. Typically it's changes like this that only happen in a new major version, so it probably changed with a new major version (e.g. 4.0.0, 5.0.0, etc.).